How to temporarily sleep only certain part of a crontab job?
I have a RHEL 8.x / Oracle Linux 8.x installation with a cronjob that runs every 3 minutes as follows. At the end of the script, you will see 4 different if's that check the different files and send e-mails according to the status.
Let's say the middle two if blocks (success|OK ones) worked and sent mail, and I want them to work again in the cronjob that will run 3 minutes later, but not send mail. And send mail in the first cronjob that will run in 1 hour. And then after sending the email, it will not send emails again for 60 minutes. So it will be a loop for each if blocks.
If I add sleep 60m, the part after the middle if block will not work for 60 minutes. However, I only want to stop a certain if block so that it does not send mail for 60 minutes, and the others will still work every 3 minutes.
Actually if there is a situation where an e-mail is sent once, I want it not to be sent for the next 60 minutes and to continue without affecting any other process in the cronjob. The same scenario will be valid for the failed ones, I just chose the two if blocks in the middle for the sake of clarity of the example.
How can I achieve this using only one cronjob?

The content of myJobScript.sh:
...
...
... 
/usr/local/bin/command -options /dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/....bin > $DIR_NAME/file1_${parameter}_${parameter}.log
/usr/local/bin/command -options /dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/....bin > $DIR_NAME/file2_${parameter}_${parameter}.log
/usr/local/bin/command -options /dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/....bin > $DIR_NAME/file3_${parameter}_${parameter}.log
/usr/local/bin/command -options /dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/....bin > $DIR_NAME/file4_${parameter}_${parameter}.log

if grep -E -w 'failure|failed|critical|warning' $DIR_NAME/file1_${parameter}_${parameter}.log >> /dev/null
then
  cat $DIR_NAME/file1_${parameter}_${parameter}.log | mailx -r mail@somemail.com -s "$parameter - something" mail@somemail2.com
fi

if grep -E -w 'success|OK' $DIR_NAME/file2_${parameter}_${parameter}.log >> /dev/null
then
  cat $DIR_NAME/file2_${parameter}_${parameter}.log | mailx -r mail@somemail.com -s "$parameter - something" mail@somemail2.com
fi

if grep -E -w 'success|OK' $DIR_NAME/file3_${parameter}_${parameter}.log >> /dev/null
then
  cat $DIR_NAME/file3_${parameter}_${parameter}.log | mailx -r mail@somemail.com -s "$parameter - something" mail@somemail2.com
fi

if grep -E -w 'failure|failed|critical|warning' $DIR_NAME/file4_${parameter}_${parameter}.log >> /dev/null
then
  cat $DIR_NAME/file4_${parameter}_${parameter}.log | mailx -r mail@somemail.com -s "$parameter - something" mail@somemail2.com
fi




Can you actually remove all the unnecessary stuff and replace it with comments explaining to what you refer to in the text? your endless "export … =…" don't help anyone, and I have NO idea what blocks you are referring to in your text.

Also, explain maybe why you're doing this in a single cronjob. Maybe start with what it does, and why it needs to be a cronjob at all.

@MarcusMüller Marcus, you really got caught up in unnecessary details. I deleted those parts for your happiness. :) I think all the explanations in my question are enough to understand the subject. If you want to help, you can give your opinion. Just criticizing does not help me. There should be only one crontab job, because the job requires it.

So, my opionion is that your question is underdefined! Voting to close as unclear, I'm afraid. Don't worry - if that happens to become the faith of your question, i.e., if enough other users come to the same assessment, it can be reopened, after you added a bit of structure, supported by context.

@MarcusMüller I respect your opinion but my question is very clear. There are 4 different if's and I ask which part I want help with. There is nothing to misunderstand in this. Bye.

I agree with @Marcus Müller that the question is unclear.  (1) Do you want /usr/local/bin/command to run four times every three minutes?  Then you want the cron job to run every three minutes, and you don’t want it to sleep for an hour.  Period.  By talking about sleeping, you’re being confusing.  (2) You say, “Let’s say the middle two if blocks (the “success|OK” ones) worked and sent mail, and I want them to work again in the cronjob that will run 3 minutes later, but not send mail.”  What does it mean for if blocks to “work” but not do anything? … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (3) “The same scenario will be valid for the failed ones, I just chose the two if blocks in the middle for the sake of clarity of the example.”  No, if you want file1, file2, file3 and file4 all to be treated the same way, and you write a paragraph saying that you want file2 and file3 to be treated that way,  that is not clear.   (4) OTOH, if you just want each email not to be sent more often than once an hour, then just say that.  But you still need to be clearer.  What if file2 succeeds at 17:12, fails at 17:15, and succeeds again at 17:18?  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  Are the files/tests independent?  What if file2 succeeds at 17:12 and file3 succeeds at 17:15?  (5) I would be astonished if there was any off-the-shelf ready-to-use command that will do what you want.  This seems like a situation where you simply need to define your requirements and write code to implement them.  (Consider creating four files that persist between runs and keep track of when emails were sent.)   (6) I can’t think of any reason to do >> /dev/null instead of > /dev/null.

On errors, arrange for the cron job to create a named file, containing a timestamp.
On the startup of the job, delete the named file if it is more than 1 hour old, otherwise omit the bits of the cron job you don't want to execute.

As long as there is still a possibility that your cron job would need to do something in 3-minute intervals, the main body of the cron job must run at that cycle. So changing the cycle time of the cron job makes no sense.
You could enclose each if block in another if block that tests for existence and age of a specific marker file. The block would be executed only if the marker file does not exist or is older than 60 minutes.
Whenever you want to put a particular if block to sleep, you would touch the marker file associated with that block (creating the marker file if it does not exist, and updating its timestamp to current if it does).
To check for the age of the marker file, you could create a temporary file at the start of the cron job with an exactly 1 hour old timestamp with touch -d "-1 hour" /tmp/marker-comparison-file, then do a
if [ ! -f /some/where/marker1 ] || [ /some/where/marker1 -ot /tmp/marker-comparison-file ]
then
    # ...if block that will only be executed if marker1 does not exist or is older than 1h
    # ...fi
fi

The /tmp/marker-comparison-file can be deleted at the end of the cron job, but the marker files should be preserved from one run of the cron job to the next.
